# Cesium Fly Camera to Location but Maintain Camera Height

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I would like to use flyTo() and provide a lat long co-ordinate but keep the camera at the same height / zoom / distance from the surface as it currently is.

I've tried to use the camera.position.z in my call to flyTo but this seems to zoom in further and further on each call to flyTo().

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way to solve the problem.

You need to take the camera's cartographic position via:

```
var currentPosition = viewer.camera.positionCartographic;

viewer.camera.setView({
    destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(50.0, 5.0, currentPosition.height)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried setting `maximumHeight`?

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;    
var height = 500000;

viewer.camera.setView({
    destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(50.0, 5.0, height)
});

setTimeout(function() {
    viewer.camera.flyTo({
        destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-117.16, 32.71, height),
        maximumHeight: height
    });
}, 2000);
```

http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=674299ee1a1bffffdc3a042018aadd2a